# Таблица в таблице

Tags: lua

Читаю книгу по lua от автора. Там есть вопрос-упражнение:

```
a = {}
a.a = a
```

Далее

```
print(a)
print(a.a)
print(a.a.a)
print(a.a.a.a)
print(a.a.a.a.a)
```

все указывают на себя:

```
table: 0x00021d60
table: 0x00021d60
table: 0x00021d60
table: 0x00021d60
table: 0x00021d60
```

Но если сделать так: `a.a.a.a = 1` или `a.a.a = 1` или `a.a = 1`
То во всех случаях выводит таблицу(себя), число и ошибку:

```
table: 0x00021cd0
1
attempt to index field 'a' (a number value)
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать для понимания почему так, а не иначе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a = {}` - создать пустую таблицу

`a.a = a` - в таблице `a` создать переменную `a`, присвоить этой переменной ссылку на таблицу `a`.

Теперь, обращаясь к переменной `a.a` вы обращаетесь к **таблице** `a`, обращаясь к `a.a.a` вы обращаетесь к полю `a` в таблице `a`, и это поле по прежнему указывает на таблицу `a`. Т.е. получается этакая рекурсия.

Если же вы в какой-то момент полю `a` присвоите число, то при обращении к этому полю вы уже получите именно то число, а не таблицу. Т.е. `a.a = 1` - в таблице `a` создать переменную `a` и присвоить ей число `1`. Очевидно, что теперь нельзя обращаться к `a.a` как к таблице - теперь это просто число. У переменной `a` в таблице `a` динамически изменился тип с **таблица** на **число**.

Comment: @flapenguin, Вы немного не так поняли мой вопрос. При присвоении `a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a = 1`, я уже не могу сделать `print(..)` дальше `a.a`, т.е. `a.a.a` выдаст ошибку.

Comment: @imsysmem Поймите, что на **любом** уровне вложенности, как только вы изменяете тип поля `a` с таблицы на число, вы не можете более обращаться к этому полю как к таблице. Т.е. и `a.a = 1` и `a.a.a.a.a.a.a.a = 1` (сколько угодно `a` после точки) выполняют абсолютно одинаковую операцию.

Answer (score 2):

Потому что таблицы хранятся по ссылкам. В `a` хранится таблица со ссылкой на саму себя. При этом у ключ `a` у таблица и `a` - это два разных `a`.

`a = {}; a.a = a`:

```
                                     +-------------+
                                     |             |
 +-----------------+        +--------v--------+    |
 |   переменные    |   +---->     таблица     |    |
 +-----------------+   |    +-----------------+    |
 |        |        |   |    |        |        |    |
 |   a    |   +--------+    |    a   |    +--------+
 |        |        |        |        |        |
 +-----------------+        +-----------------+
 |       ...       |
 +-----------------+
```

Затем ссылка на саму себя перетирается числом. `a.a.a.a.a.a = 1`:

```
 +-----------------+        +-----------------+
 |   переменные    |   +---->     таблица     |
 +-----------------+   |    +-----------------+
 |        |        |   |    |        |        |
 |   a    |   +--------+    |    a   |   1    |
 |        |        |        |        |        |
 +-----------------+        +-----------------+
 |       ...       |
 +-----------------+
```